# "Был уже двенадцатый час" — это "когда"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Здравствуйте. Иностранец тут. Мы с коллегой спорим по поводу...

**"Был уже двенадцатый час. Князь знал, что у Епанчиных в городе он может застать теперь одного только генерала..."**
(Ф.М.Достоевский, "Идиот")

*"Уже двенадцатый час" — **это "когда"?*** Между 11:00 и 12:00? Или 12:00 и 01:00?

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

"Был уже двенадцатый час".

***Это между 11:00 и 12:00.*** *А точнее — **между 11:00 и 11:30***.

Comment: Матвей, а после 11:30, например 11:40 - это не двенадцатый час?

Comment: Может, я субъективен, но после 11:30-ти для меня уже не двенадцатый час, а без двадцати двенадцать и т.п. Разве 11:50 это тоже двенадцатый час?

Comment: Я вообще считаю, что с 11.01 - по 11:59 - это двенадцатый час. Может, и ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно говорят «шёл 12-й час». Выражение «был 12-й час», или как в вопросе «Уже двенадцатый час — это когда?», равносильно словам «пробило 12». Ответ дать не трудно, глядя на циферблат, визуально отслеживая положение часовой стрелки. В теории: стрелка ведёт отсчёт минут того часа, который не закончен ещё.

Что до выражения «шёл 12-й час», то имеется в виду интервал со средним значением 11:25.

Answer (score 0):

Это между 11 и 12 часами или между 23 и 24 часами.

Comment: В 11:30 уж был двенадцатый?

Comment: двенадцатый час с 11:00:0000...0001 до 11:59:59999999999(9)

Comment: Глагол не игнорируйте! Он в Вопросе — на первом месте, если что... Вы решили без него обойтись и даже без тире.